# Jquery Ajax in paste.kde.org

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

Hello there Iam trying to use the [http://paste.kde.org](http://paste.kde.org/doc/api/) api in order to make it work
My code seems like

```
var p = {};
p.id=122083;
p.mode='json';

$.ajax({
url: 'http://paste.kde.org/show.php',
data: p,
success: function(data) {
   alert(data.result.id);
}

});
```

The output json is like :

```
{ "result": { "id": "122083", "author": "Anonymous", "timestamp": "1316135671", "language": "text", "data": "testing the app" } }
```

But I can;t make it work, also i have no alerts in the creation  of the "pastes" although i can see them created in the paste.kde.org archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that paste.kde allows for ajax requests to their api. When attempting to run your code from jsfiddle, I got the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://paste.kde.org/show.php?id=122083&mode=json. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

paste.kde.org would need to change their response headers to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header so that your ajax request could complete.

You could change your request so that your `$.ajax` call goes to your local server (let's say it's using PHP), and then you could run a `curl` request to the kde API, and then have your PHP script parrot back the results from paste.kde.org.

Comment: Sure i can do it but, i need to use only client server techniques, as i can see i think that I can use this api, through the paste is created

Comment: I am planning to release a newer version of the pastebin (v1.0) very soon. I'll try to add this feature before I move paste.kde.org to the newer version.